# confirmação de senha em c

Tags: c, array, struct

Eu preciso cadastrar N pessoas no meu programa com duas informações apenas: nome e senha. Depois o usuario insere um nome, se este nome não estiver cadastrado o programa exibe uma mensagem de não cadastramento e fecha, mas se tver cadastrado ele pergunta a senha, se a senha estiver certa o programa só mostra uma mensagem se acesso permitido, se a senha estiver errada o usuario tem 3 chances de acertar, se nas 3 chances ele errar o programa fecha. O problema é que meu programa esta pegando a senha da pessoa 1 e adicionando o nome da pessoa 2 e não estou conseguindo identificar o erro, uma vez que a senha tem apenas 6 campos de memoria.

```
#define N 5
struct pessoa
{
    char nome[30];
    char senha[6];
};
int main()
{
    struct pessoa cadastro[N];
    int i,j;
    char nome[30],senha[6];

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        puts("\nDigite o nome:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cadastro[i].nome);
        puts("\nInsira uma senha de ate 6 digitos:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cadastro[i].senha);
    }

    system("cls");
    puts("\nInsira um nome:");//nome de busca
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nome);


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {

        printf("%s",cadastro[i].senha);// este printf só coloquei pra ver o que estava sendo armazenado em cadast[i].senha
        if(strcmp(cadastro[i].nome,nome)==0)
        {
            do
            {
                puts("\nInforme sua senha:");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(senha);
                if(strcmp(cadastro[i].senha,senha)==0)
                {
                    j=0;
                    puts("\nAcesso permitido.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    j=j+1;
                    puts("\nSenha incorreta.");
                    if(j==3)
                    {
                        break;
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }while (j!=0);

        }
        else
        {puts("\nNome nao cadastrado.\n");}break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ana, fiz assim e estar a funcionar, o seu problema deve ser em relação ao buffer, ja que esta utilizando fflush, ou gets para ler as strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Pessoa {
    char nome[20];
    int senha;
    struct Pessoa *arr;
};

void limpaBuffer() {
    char ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
struct Pessoa* leitura() {

    struct Pessoa *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Pessoa));
    p->arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct Pessoa));

    printf("\tCadastrando Usuarios\n");
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
       printf("\nEntre com o nome: ");
       gets(p->arr[i].nome); //aqui poderia usar o fgets, mas daria muito trabalho para por o carctere '\0' no final
       printf("Entre com a senha: ");
       scanf("%d", &p->arr[i].senha);
       limpaBuffer();
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    struct Pessoa *p;
    p = leitura();

    int contador = 0;
    char nome[20];
    int senha;

    printf("\n\n\tVerificando Usuario\n");

    do {

        printf("\nEntre com o Usuario: ");
        gets(nome);
        printf("Entre com a senha: ");
        scanf("%d", &senha);
        limpaBuffer();
        ++contador;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(nome, p->arr[i].nome) && senha == p->arr[i].senha) {
            printf("\nParabens voce acertou!");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("\nVoce errou! Restam %d tentativas.", 3 - contador);
            break;
        }
      }
    }while(contador < 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Se quiser algo melhor leia de um arquivo, ou use listas encadeadas.